# Passing Data from a Controller to a View (not displaying it) then passing back to different Controller in Codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, button

I am trying to a create a View which provides a summary table of various site members profiles - then each summary has a button, that once clicked, takes the user to that member's full profile.  I can get the summary page to work properly, but I cant get the second part -where the button takes the user to the members full profile to work.

Here is my controller:

```
public function network_barre()
        {
        $this->load->model("Profiles_model"); 
        $style ='barre';
        $profilesubdata["fetch_data"] = $this->Profiles_model->fetch_data($style);
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/page-network_barre', $profilesubdata);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Here is my Model "Profiles Model"

```
function fetch_data($style)  
              {  
                $this->db->select("username, email, style, about");  
                $this->db->from("profiles");
                $this->db->where('style', $style);
                $query = $this->db->get();  
                return $query;  
              }
```

Here is the view

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center card-top">
          
           <?php 
            if($fetch_data->num_rows()>0)
            {
             foreach ($fetch_data->result() as $row)  
            {  
            ?>
                           
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
           
           <div class="card card-warning wow zoomInUp mb-4 animation-delay-5">
              <div class="withripple zoom-img">
               <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/img/demo/avatar4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
               </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <span class="badge badge-warning pull-right"><?php echo $row->style; ?></span>
                <h3 class="color-warning"><?php echo $row->username; ?></h3>
                  <p><?php $string=character_limiter($row->about, 255, '&#8230(More in Profile)') ; echo $string?></p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col text-center">
                    <!-- BUTTON -->
                    <form method="POST" action="<?php  echo base_url(); ?>public_area/gotopublicprofile/<?php echo $row->email; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-sm btn-warning" name="submit"  value="submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i>Profile</button>
                    </form>
                    
                     
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <?php    //this tag close out php tags above 
                }
                } 
            ?>   
          
         </div>
      </div>
```

here is Controller gotopublicprofile

```
function gotopublicprofile()
        {
        $this->load->model("profiles_model");     
        $email = '$this->uri->segment(3)'; 
        $profiledata["fetch_profiledata"] = $this->Profiles_model->fetch_profiledata($email);       
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/page-profilepublic', $profiledata);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

And here is the fetch_profiledata function in the Model:

```
function fetch_profiledata($email)  
            {  
            $this->db->where('email', $email);  
            $query = $this->db->get("profiles");  
            return $query;  
            }
```

I always get these error messages:

Undefined property: Public_area::$Profiles_model

AND

Call to a member function fetch_profiledata() on null

I am sure I am just missing something simple, as lots of websites use this approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks but, in addition to the otehr error messages, I also now get: "Object of class CI_URI could not be converted to string".

Comment: dont use quote at all `$email = $this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: Ok - now I am right back to where I started with the same two error messages.  The address bar does show the email thou....

Comment: can you show your `fetch_profiledata` function?

Comment: Case of model name is different in `gotopublicprofile` function

Comment: Hi @kirb, I added the fetch_profiledata function to my original question above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out..it was a combination of little things:

First

```
 $email = '$this->uri->segment(3)';
```

became

```
 $email = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Thanks @kirb! and

```
function gotopublicprofile()
        {
        $this->load->model("profiles_model");
```

became

```
function gotopublicprofile()
        {
        $this->load->model("Profiles_model");
```

Thanks @Atal Prateek!